# AWS ElasticSearch Transition to UltraWarm Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using AWS ElasticSearch service, and am attempting to use a policy to transition indices to UltraWarm storage. However, each time the migration to UltraWarm begins, Kibana displays the error, "Failed to start warm migration" for the managed index. The complete error message is below. The "cause" is not very helpful. I am looking for help on how to identify / resole the root cause of this issue. Thanks!

```
{
    "cause": "[753f6f14e4f92c962243aec39d5a7c31][10.212.32.199:9300][indices:admin/ultrawarm/migration/warm]",
    "message": "Failed to start warm migration"
}
```